# How to add cookies with HttpOnly and Secure flags in Spring Webflux webclient?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

Current to set the cookies in SpringWebFlux web client, I am manually adding cookies with the equal sign like name1=value;name2=value;name3-value and adding it to the header with Cookie key.

```
webclient.get().header("Cookie",name1=value;name2=value;name3-value);
```

But I don't know how to add **HttpOnly or Secure flag** for these cookies being added.Please let me know how to add these flags while making REST calls to the Https URL using spring webclient ? I couldn't find a way to add these flags. Adding these flags mandatory if the connection is over HTTPS ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I am manually adding cookies with the equal sign like name1=value;name2=value;name3-value and adding it to the header with Cookie key.

This is a very odd way of doing things - you can add cookies directly with `WebClient` by using `webclient.get().cookie()`.

> But I don't know how to add HttpOnly or Secure flag for these cookies being added.

You can't, and you don't need to - these are flags sent by the *server* to the *client* to detail restrictions that the *browser* should enforce in handling these cookies. It therefore makes no sense to set those flags when sending the cookies to the server - there's no useful behaviour the server would be able to take based on those flags.